# How to send a activity feed notification with a query on Teams?

Tags: notifications, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I've been developing a Teams Custom App with the TeamsFx SDK. I want to send a activity feed notification with a query.

I tried the HTTP request as below, however the app wasn't able to recieve a query(hoge=123).

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user id}/teamwork/sendActivityNotification
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "topic": {
        "source": "entityUrl",
        "value": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user id}/teamwork/installedApps/{installation id}?hoge=123"
    },
    "activityType": "taskCreated",
    "previewText": {
        "content": "New Task Created"
    },
    "templateParameters": [
        {
            "name": "taskId",
            "value": "Task 12322"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any wat to send a activity feed notification with a query?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on activity feed notification with a query and share the repro steps, so that we can try it from our end.

Comment: My procedure is...
1. I created a new Teams app from "SSO-enabled tab" sample with Teams Toolkit on Visual Studio Code.
2. I deployed the project to Microsoft Azure.

Comment: 3. I edited a manifest.json as below to receive a activity feed notification.
--------
   "webApplicationInfo": {
        "id": "de8bc8b5-d9f9-48b1-a8ad-b748da725064",
        "resource": "Graph Explorer"
    },
    "activities": {
        "activityTypes": [
            {
                "type": "taskCreated",
                "description": "A new task is created.",
                "templateText": "{actor} created task {taskId} for you"
            }
        ]
    }
--------

4. I sent a activity feed notification form Microsoft Graph Explorer as I posted on first question.

Comment: Are you looking same-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/graph-activity-feed/csharp